# Maven- how to find the group id responsible for the jar file my current project is using?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

Im having issues in finding the group id of the jar file my maven project is using. basically i want to add new version of that group id,artifact id in pom.xml so that new version of jar gets downloaded from nexus.

[i already referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237875/how-to-know-groupid-and-artifactid-of-any-external-jars-in-maven-android-project)

my jar currently looks like 
**/Users/harish/.m2/spring/com/local/api/platform/hike/AccountsSpecification/xxxx-creditaccounts-specification/1.5/xxxx-creditaccounts-specification-1.5.jar**

and i dont see any of my pom.xml file with **xxxx-creditaccounts-specification** as artifact id.

kindly help me figure out which group id and artifact id is responsible for my jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this dependency is transitive. You can use [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) in order to find the origin. For example you could run in the root directory and inspect the output:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

It could be helpful to find the dependency but update of this dependency wouldn't be straightforward if it's transitive.

Comment: also one more thing can you help how to find the respective git repository for this artifact id? it is possible it is very silly question, but im still learning please help